# public OptionSet with private constructor

Tags: swift

I have a sample code:

```
public struct MyOptions: OptionSet {
    public let rawValue: Int

    public init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    public static let one = MyOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    public static let two = MyOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1)
}
```

In other module I can do:

```
print(MyOptions.one)
print(MyOptions(rawValue: 10))
```

How can I do public struct with private constructor and public static properties(like a *one*, *two*) to limit manual creation?

Comment: you can limit manual creation adding a precondition to your initializer `precondition(1...2 ~= rawValue)`

Comment: `struct MyOptions: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) {
        precondition(1...2 ~= rawValue)
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
    static let one = 1
    static let two = 2
}`

Comment: Looks like a crutch. Is this the only way out?

Comment: Well even if you don't create the initializer you can still create it manually. I don't know whats the purpose of it so I can't really help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (or prevent) by making the init method private?

Comment: The simple fact is that `OptionSet` *needs* the `init(rawValue:)` initialiser in order to perform bitwise arithmetic (i.e form the union/intersections between two option sets) – so it has to be public. As others have said, what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. When you conform a type to a protocol, all the required stubs' protection levels must be at least equal to the type's protection level. I'll try to explain why.

Let's say I have a type `Foo` that I conform to `Hashable`. I then assign an instance as a `Hashable` type:

```
let foo: Hashable = Foo()
```

Because the instance is of type `Hashable`, I am guaranteed to have access to the `hash(into:)` method. But what if I make the method private? At that point you end up with unexpected behavior. Either for some reason I can't access a method that I was guaranteed access to, or I have access to a method that I shouldn't be able to reach. It's a conflict of access levels.

So yeah, what you want to do isn't possible.